# What's a working strategy for "With our powers combined" trophy?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, achievements

Minecraft 1.19 update came with new PS4 trophies, and I'm trying to get [With our powers combined](https://psnprofiles.com/trophy/13113-minecraft-set-2/10-with-our-powers-combined) in a legit way.
This trophy requires to:

> Have all 3 froglights in your inventory

A [froglight](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Froglight) is a luminous natural block that can be obtained **if a frog eats a tiny Magma cube**. Moreover, there are 3 colors of froglight that drop depending on what type of Frog kills the Magma cube:

- pearlescent (purple) from warm frogs
- verdant (green) from cold frogs
- ochre (yellow) from temperate frogs

Frogs only spawn in Swamps (temperate species) and in the new Mangrove Swamp biome (warm species). So my first problem is that I need a cold Frog: for what I understood the Frog species is determined by the biome in which the Tadpole grew up. I can catch Tadpoles in a bucket, in this way I can easily move them to another biome.

The main problem is that Frogs spawn in Overworld, while Magma cubes only spawn in the Nether, and only in certain biomes.

So, here's my question:
Should I gather 3 species of Frogs and move them in a Nether portal, hoping to find Magma cubes to kill? Or should I leave my Frogs outside of a portal and make Magma cubes to follow me in the Overworld, in order to let the Frogs eat them?

Or am I missing an easier strategy to do this?

Comment: What's easiest for you is going to largely depend on factors like biome distribution in both the nether and the overworld. If you've got a basalt delta near your nether portal, or a bastion, it's probably easier to take the frogs to the nether. If you haven't, then bringing magma cubes to the overworld might be easier.

Comment: @JonK I do have a basalt delta near my Nether portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get all 3 Froglights!

Since [slimes can't get into boats](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-128160), I had to move my frogs to the Nether.

Firstly, I catched a bunch of Tadpoles in a bucket in order to place them in the correct biome and then feed them with Slimeballs.

Luckily, one of my friend's base has a Nether portal located in a Basalt delta, which is near a Bamboo Jungle, and there I obtained the white frog (warm). Quite every standard biome is considered temperate, so I easily got the brown frog. The hardest one to get was the cold frog, and I had to travel a lot on boat to find a Frozen Ocean biome.

I moved the frogs on boat when possible, and on rail in the Nether. The rest was a piece of cake, Magma cubes spawn often, and the trophy popped!

PS: I "tagged" every frog with a nametag, because you'll never know...

Answer (score 0):

The strategy can largely be borrowed from the strategy used to get shulkers into the overworld. Get one of the two groups into boats and transport them. I would suggest putting the magma cubes into the boats to make them defenseless against the frogs.

Comment: [Slimes can't get into boats](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-128160), unfortunately...